# Access an ActiveRelation in a view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have two models with the appropriate foreign key created in the people table:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :family

class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :people
```

If I do the following I get an object - @family_members - as an instance variable and I have no problems:

```
@family_members = Family.find(1)
```

I can access the 'child' people table fields easily in my view:

```
@family_members.people.first_name
```

However, if I use the arel way with "where" etc. I get an "ActiveRecord::Relation", not a normal object, which leaves me stumped as to how to access the same "first_name" field form the people table like I accessed above:

```
@family_members = Family.where(:id => 1) 
or even
@family_members = Family.joins(:people).where(:id => 1)
```

(is the "joins" even required??) 
I understand that using ".first" will cause the query to run:

```
@family_members = Family.where(:id => 1).first
```

But it returns an array, not an object, so if I use in my view:

```
@family_members.people.first_name
```

I get a "method 'people' unknown" error.

How can I access the 'first_name' field of the people table like I did with the object created by "find" but using an ActiveRecord relation?

* added information 7/15 **************

To clarify what I am looking for -- here is what I would have written if I were writing SQL instead of Arel:

```
SELECT f.home_phone, f.address, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.birthday 
FROM families f INNER JOIN people p ON p.family.id = f.id WHERE family_id = 1
```

With that query's results loaded into a result set I could access:

```
myResultSet("home_phone") -- the home_phone from the families table
myResultSet("address") -- the address from the families table
myResultSet("first_name") -- the first_name from the people table
myResultSet("birthdate") -- the birthdate from the people table
```

If the two tables in the query have a same-named field I would just use "AS" to request one of the fields by another name.
I have used this kind of query/result set for many years in web apps and I am trying to deduce how to do the same in Rails and ActiveRecord.

Comment: `Family.where(:id => 1).first` shouldn't be returning an array, it ought to be a `Family` object. `first` is an array method, and like you stated causes the query to execute. Double check to see that you've got everything typed up correctly.

Comment: Your example `@family_members.people.first_name` shouldn't be working.

Answer (score 0):

`@family_members.people.first_name` shouldn't ever work so I'm surprised you find it working  ... @family_members contains a Family object, @family_members.people is an array of Person objects.

The fact that you're calling it `@family_members` seems to make me think you're expecting it to be an array of Persons... in which case the correct code would be...

```
@family_members = Family.find(1).people # finds people in first Family object
```

If you expect @family_members to contain just the first family member, then...

```
@family_members = Family.find(1).people.first
```

If you want an array of first names of all family members, then...

```
@family_members = Family.find(1).people # finds people in 1st Family object
@family_members.map {|member| member.first_name} # array of first_name
```

`@family_members = Family.find(1)` and `@family_members = Family.where(:id => 1)` are functionally identical.. both retrieve the first Family object in the database in each case may contain zero, one, or multiple people.

Just to be clear, the "1" in all examples above refer to which Family object is retrieved, not which Person in the Family.

Comment: Thank you Steve. That helps. What I am wanting is a result set in some form (array/hash or object) that has fields from both the family and people tables like in the results of the query I posted in the updated version of my question. I would like to get it using .where() and not find - if I use find I'm OK because that syntax that no one thinks should work is working fine in many places in my app. I read it in one of the books I am using to learn but I don't recall which one.